# Microsoft Translator (Azure) returns questions mark instead of text

Tags: azure

When translating from English to Russian it only returns questions marks for the words.

Comment: "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/translate?text=Hello my name is Willie&from=en&to=ru"

Comment: Set oCon = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
cURLGo = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13"